# Java android performance array: access class getter directly or create local copy

Tags: java, android, performance

From a performance point of view, i have a

```
class someClass {
     private List<type> data;
     public List<type> getData()
     {
          return data;
     }

}

class someOtherClass {
    private someClass instance;
    private someMethod() {

         // heavy loop
         for (...) {

         }
    }

}
```

is more efficient in a heavy loop calling directly (maybe more than one time)

```
instance.getData().get(index).someOtherMethod();
```

or is more appropriate to make something like this before the loop:

```
localData = someClass.getData();
```

and use `localData` for every need inside the loop?

---

EDIT: supposing that the getData() method does some other things, the compiler optimization is still valid?

```
class someClass {
     private List<type> data;
     public List<type> getData()
     {
          makeSomething();
          return data;
     }

}
```

Comment: usually the underlying compiler optimizes such things for you. You must use what is more readable.

Comment: Incidentally, your code examples are confusing. Where is the `instance.get()` method defined?

Comment: sorry... fixed instance.get()

Comment: why don't you try profiling it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If efficient is what you want actually `get(index)` is `O(n)` plus you are in a forloop which make it `O(n^2)` **big-O**

Rather than using a regular forloop use the enhance forloop

**sample:**

```
for(someClass s: yourList){}
```

Now without calling the `get(index)` using the enhance forloop will make it `O(n)` rather than `O(n^2)`

Comment: `get(index)` complexity depends on the class implementing the List interface. From the javadocs, for ArrayList: The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. For LinkedList: All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list. Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.